# Group and display rows based on column values in r

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO7zT.png)

I want to group the rows based on the column "Rating" and then display the rows in each group which has the max One_Year_Return. I am new to R and not able to write the code. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please add an example for reproducibility of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Dplyr approach**

You can use the *dplyr package* for data transformation operations.

```
install.packages("dplyr")    # install the dplyr package
library(dplyr)     # load the package in your work environment
your_data %>%
   group_by(Rating) %>%      # group your data based on the variable Rating
   arrange(desc(One_Year_Return)) %>%     # order in descending order the variable One_Year_Return
   slice(1)    # extract the first row (the observation with the highest return of each group)
```

- Read more in the chapter 5 of the book [R For Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html).
- The operator %>% take the variable of the left hand side of the operator and put as the first argument of the function of the right hand side. For example,

  ```
  your_data %>% group_by(Rating)
  # is equivalent to...
  group_by(your_data, Rating)
  ```
- The pipe operator (%>%) allows you to chain multiple operations together without the neccesity of store intermediate steps in temporal variables.

**Another approach with base R functions could be:**

```
# create a list of data frames for each rating value
by_rating <- split(your_data, your_data$Rating)

# then subset the first row of each data set previosly ordered
lapply(by_rating, function(df) df[order(df$One_Year_Return, decreasing = TRUE), ][1, ])
```

The important in the last approach is understanding the *lapply* function and the concept of anonymous functions.